# Extending a ModelForm with a ForeignKey field that was previously excluded

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
class Watchman(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('groups.Group')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

And the following model form:

```
class NewWatchmanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Watchman
        fields = ['name']
```

At the time the new Watchman is created, I do not know which `group` it belongs to, hence `name` is the only model field defined in `NewWatchmanForm`. However, once I do figure out the correct `group` it belongs to, I use this form to update the object with the appropriate `group`:

```
class UpdateWatchmanForm(NewWatchmanForm):
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())
    class Meta(NewWatchmanForm.Meta):
        fields = NewWatchmanForm.Meta.fields + ("group",)
```

I was curious if there might be a better way to reuse my `NewWatchmanForm`. Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to declare the `group` explicitly, something like this:

```
class UpdateWatchmanForm(NewWatchmanForm):
    # group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())
    class Meta(NewWatchmanForm.Meta):
        fields = NewWatchmanForm.Meta.fields + ("group",)
```

However, if I do that, I get this error:

```
fields = NewWatchmanForm.Meta.fields + ("group",)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

What is the correct way to subclass an existing ModelForm and include a ForeignKey field (without redefining `forms.ModelChoiceField(...)`)?

Answer (score 0):

I should have actually tried reading the error :|

The problem was that I was trying to concatenate a list with a tuple. Turns out that removing the `group` field in the subclass works just fine:

```
class UpdateWatchmanForm(NewWatchmanForm):
    class Meta(NewWatchmanForm.Meta):
        # Extend list with a list, not a tuple!
        fields = NewWatchmanForm.Meta.fields + ["group"]
```